# regex that replaces all commas with nothing and removes everything between paretheses

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

What is the regex I can use in javascript to replace all commas in a string with nothing and remove everything between `(` and `)` including those characters.

So in other words replace , and everything between and including ( and ) with nothing ( '' )?

Comment: Did you make any attempts to solve it?

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: @anubhava I am new to regex, but I tried the string.replace(',', '') and that always leaves one comma left.

Comment: Can you be more specific or give examples? What should `abc(def)ghi(jkl)mno` resolve to? `abcmno` or `abcghimno`? What about `abc(def(ghi))`? `abc` or `abc)`?

Comment: Please show the code you used in the question and in context

Comment: there won't be a case with `ababc(def)ghi(jkl)mno`. Nothing happens to `abcmno` nor `abcghimno`. `abc(def(ghi))` becomes `abc`.

Comment: I know you accepted an answer already, but do look at the escaped parentheses discussion in my answer, it may be helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
newstr = str.replace(/,|\(.*?\)/g, '')
```

- `,` matches comma
- `|` specifies alternatives.
- `\(.*?\)` matches a pair of parentheses and everything between them.

Note that this doesn't do parenthesis balancing. It matches from an open parenthesis to the closest close parenthesis. Matching balanced constructs requires recursive regular expressions, which Javascript doesn't have.

Comment: I realy don't like the `.*?` part... I often use the negation syntax  : 
`\([^\)]*\)`

Comment: @PatrickFerreira What you suggest is in my (strangely unpopular) answer. :) Note that you don't need to escape the parenthesis in the character class, so `[^)]` is enough.

Comment: Thank you very much. Also for explaining it. I appreciate that.

Comment: @PatrickFerreira I just did a search for SO questions about negation versus non-greedy quantifiers. Opinions seem mixed. There are some cases where they can have different results, I don't think this is one of them.

Comment: Nice answer, but I'm confused as to why you got all the love. :)

Comment: If the string contains carriage returns, the non-greedy will stop at the end of the line, the negation goes througt it :-) but as you said, it depends on the needs ,)

Comment: @PatrickFerreira That can be resolved using the `s` modifier to make `.` match newlines, if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

At the most bare-bone level, this does the trick:

Search: `,|\([^)]*\)`  Replace: `""`

In JS:

```
result = string.replace(/,|\([^)]*\)/g, "");
```

**Refinements**

Some potential problems may arise:

1. What if we have nested parentheses?
2. What if we have escaped parentheses within a parenthesis, such as `\)`?

JS is not equipped with to handle nested parentheses in regex (which calls for recursion or balancing groups), although some tricks can get you some of the way there.

Escaped parentheses are easier to handle: we can change the regex to

```
,|\((?:\\[()]|[^()])*\)
```

The `\\[()]` allows us to match escaped parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the g (global) flag to replace all occurrences:

```
var testStr = 'this,is,a,string and this is (everything else) something else (Hello WOrld)';
testStr = testStr.replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\(.+\)/g, "");

console.log(testStr)
```

Click here to test: http://jsfiddle.net/WLW8y/

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a RegEx for this. I would leverage JavaScripts string raplce() function.

```
 var findComma = ",";
 var stringToSearch = "My, First, Replace, Function";
 var outputString = stringToSearch.replace(findComma, "-");
 document.write(outputString);
```